# Nested Select in From Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Server,

you can write nested SQL like this:

```
SELECT T.con
FROM (SELECT count(*) as "con" FROM EMP) AS T
```

In such way, I can get a temp table T that can be nested into other query.

But I cannot do the same thing in oracle SQL

It gives me `ORA-01747:invalid column`

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT count(*) as "con" FROM EMP) T
```

select * works, but it's not what I want. Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query you posted works fine for me whether I specify the alias explicitly or whether I specify a `*`.  Can you post the exact query you're running when you get the exception?

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM (SELECT count(*) as "con" FROM EMP) T;

       con
----------
        14

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT "con"
  2* FROM (SELECT count(*) as "con" FROM EMP) T
SQL> /

       con
----------
        14
```

My guess would be that you're trying to select `con` without the double-quotes.  If you use a double-quoted identifier in Oracle, you're telling Oracle that you want the identifier to be case-sensitive which, in turns, means that you always have to refer to it in a case-sensitive manner and you have to enclose the column name in double quotes every time.  I would strongly advise against using case sensitive identifiers in Oracle.

Comment: double-quotes is the answer! Perhaps MQ-SQL is not case-sensitive do double-quotes are not needed to so such operation. Thanks, that helps a lot

Comment: @Justin Cave Why do we need the `T` at the end?

Comment: @Geek - The alias is not strictly needed in Oracle (it is required in other databases).  It's generally a good idea to alias anything you `SELECT`, though, because that makes it easier in the future when you want to join to another table and when you want to make sure that another developer can see which table a particular column is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ORA-01747 occurs usually with reserved words but as far as I know `con` is not a reserved word. Anyway, try:

```
select t.* 
  from (select count(*) count_emp from emp) t
```