# How does a sub query in the from clause work?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

What is a valid use-case for Sub Query in the FROM clause? How does that scheme work? There are many examples of this type in SO. A link to one of those is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9025823/1527084) but I can't see how this scheme works.

P.S: If the answer is Oracle specific it is fine.

Comment: You may aggregate in the sub query and use window functions or `over` clauses in the "super query".

Comment: Hmm. Isn't that the most common type of subquery? As to how it works, you can think of it as a query from a table that happens to contain the exact same data as the subquery returns. (Unless the query is dependent on super-query columns, then it gets more complicated to understand). Can you be a bit more specific in the question? Which part do you find confusing? Maybe post an example query.

Comment: @Michael can you provide an example with an answer please.

Comment: @Thilo generally after FROM we expect a table name. But in this case it is another query. I am looking for an example where this is useful and most common.

Comment: It's to do with set-based processing. A query takes one or more sets of rows (e.g. tables) and returns another set of rows. It therefore makes sense to take the resulting set of rows and perform another query *on that new set*. In this way very complex processing can be done while allowing the DBMS to optimise it for high performance.

Comment: Jeffery Kemp is right about the processing. Moreover, this type of subqueries are called `inline view`s. These act, as explained in the comment above, as a source of already processed (aggregated, joined, etc.) data. A lot depends on exactly what your case is. If you could explain it in your question we would be able to provide an answer. BTW, check this - http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view

Comment: @Geek for the examples see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here are some use cases for a subquery in the from clause. How it works has been explained in the comments to your question (SQL is mathematical closed thanks to its relational operators).

**1. Pivot (SQL Server 2008)**

```
 select P.RUN_ID
      , [2012] = sum(P.[2012])
      , [2013] = sum(P.[2013])
      , [2014] = sum(P.[2014])
      , [2015] = sum(P.[2015])
   from (select T.RUN_ID
              , Y.YEAR
              , T.MEASURE
           from SOME_TABLE T
          inner join
                YEAR Y
                  on T.SOME_ID = Y.SOME_ID
        ) T
  pivot (
          sum(MEASURE)
          for YEAR in ([2012], [2013], [2014], [2015])
        ) P
  group by
        P.RUN_ID
  order by
        P.RUN_ID
```

**2. over clause (Oracle) based on a union**

```
 select S.Text_ID
      , row_number() over (partition by S.Text_ID order by S.Segmentstart) as Segmentnumber
      , S.Segment_ID
      , S.Segmentstart
      , S.Segmentend
      , S.Segmentfragment
   from (select S.Text_ID as Text_ID
              , S.Satz_ID as Segment_ID
              , S.Start as Segmentstart
              , S.End as Segmentend
              , S.Fragment as Segmentfragment
           from Mainclauses S
          union all
         select X.ID as Text_ID
              , null as Segment_ID
              , coalesce(S.End, 0) as Segmentstart
              , lead(S.Start, 1, X.CONTENT_LENGTH) over (partition by X.ID order by S.Start) as Segmentend
              , 'X' as Segmentfragment
           from Texts X
           left join
                Mainclauses S
                  on X.ID = S.Text_ID
          union all
         select X.ID as Text_ID
              , null as Segment_ID
              , 0 as Segmentstart
              , min(S.Start) as Segmentend
              , 'X' as Segmentfragment
           from Texts X
          inner join
                Mainclauses S
                  on X.ID = S.Text_ID
          group by
                X.ID
        ) S
```

**3. over clause (SQL Server 2008) with join and aggregate**

```
 select E.X_ID
      , Z.SomeThing
      , sum(Z.OtherMeasure * E.Measure) as CombinedMeasure
      , Sorting = row_number() over
          ( partition by
                      E.X_ID
                order by
                      Z.SomeThing
          )
   from (select E.X_ID
              , E.Y_ID
              , Measure = sum(E.Measure)
           from SomeTable E
          group by
                E.X_ID
              , E.Y_ID
        ) E
  inner join
        OtherTable Z
           on E.Y_ID     = Z.Y_ID
```

**4. Calculate ratio (SQL Server 2008)**

```
   with SomeData
      ( Main_ID
      , Sub_ID
      , Measure
      )
   as (select Main_ID
            , Sub_ID
            , Measure = sum(Measure)
         from SomeTable P
        group by
              Main_ID
            , Sub_ID
      )
 select Main_ID
      , Sub_ID
      , Ratio = D.Measure / sum(M.Measure) over (partition by M.Main_ID)
   from SomeData D
  inner join
        (select Main_ID
              , Measure = sum(Measure)
           from SomeData
          group by
                Main_ID
         having sum(Measure) != 0
        ) M
           on M.Main_ID = D.Main_ID
```

**5. Partial Comparision of two (or more) tables (SQL Server 2008)**

```
select *
  from (select A, M = sum(M) from S group by A) X
  full outer join
       (select A, M = sum(M) from T group by A) Y
          on X.A = Y.A
 where X.A is null
    or Y.A is null
    or abs(X.M - Y.M) > 0.00000001
```

Note: These are examples only and in I thought that the subquery in the from clause have been a good solution to achieve the result.

Comment: i know this is a bit old but i just cant find the answer to this question...... The 5th example that you show....select *
  from (select A, M = sum(M) from S group by A) X    <------ why is the X necessary?  Also the Y

Comment: @MT32 it is required by the syntax and in this special case it necessary to make a unique reference to the column `A`. BTW there is an error in the `where` clause of the example ... i'm going to correct it.